# Heavy bug in Apple's Reachability source code? (reachabilityForLocalWiFi)

Tags: iphone, ios

I wanted to integrate a network status notification into my project and used Apples's Reachability class for this. Nevertheless I might have found a bug in their code or it maybe also caused by the simulator itself.

Code Here:

```
- (void)start {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateStatus:) 
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    Reachability *wifi = [[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] retain];
    [wifi startNotifier];

}

- (void)updateStatus:(NSNotification *)notice {
    NetworkStatus s = [[notice object] currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(s == NotReachable) {
        NSLog(@"Wifi not reachable");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Wifi is reachable");
    }
}
```

Now, what happens when "start" is called:

1) the updateStatus message isn't fired - okay, might be not a bug, maybe it is normal behaviour

2) the updateStatus message is fired, when I switch my Mac's Airport off and then the networkstatus is eq. to "NotReachable", BUT when I turn the Mac's Airport on again the updateStatus message will be fired AND THE NETWORKSTATUS STAYS "NotReachable"

When I add in the start method a timer, doing separate requests on the status

```
- (void)start {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateStatus:) 
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    Reachability *wifi = [[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] retain];
    [wifi startNotifier];

    /* Added */
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5F target:self selector:@selector(updateSeparately:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    /* * */

}
```

and the "updateSeparately" method itself

```
/* Added */
- (void)updateSeparately:(NSTimer *)timer {

    NetworkStatus s = [[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(s == NotReachable) {
        NSLog(@"updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"updateSeparately:Wifi is reachable");
    }
}
/* * */
```

gives me the following outputs in the console for the next scenarios:

1) AirPort is turned on, I start the App and turn the AirPort off

```
...
2011-07-21 09:41:41.242 MyProject[7091:207] updateSeparately:Wifi is reachable
2011-07-21 09:41:41.742 MyProject[7091:207] updateSeparately:Wifi is reachable
2011-07-21 09:41:42.242 MyProject[7091:207] updateSeparately:Wifi is reachable
2011-07-21 09:41:42.264 MyProject[7091:207] --- Status Change ---
2011-07-21 09:41:42.265 MyProject[7091:207] Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:41:42.743 MyProject[7091:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:41:43.243 MyProject[7091:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:41:43.743 MyProject[7091:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
...
```

this seems to be correct

2) after the AirPort has been turned off I turn it on again (App still running)

```
...
2011-07-21 09:45:42.702 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:43.202 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:43.701 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:43.795 MyProject[7133:207] --- Status Change ---
2011-07-21 09:45:43.795 MyProject[7133:207] Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:44.200 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:44.700 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:45.200 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi not reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:45.701 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi is reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:46.201 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi is reachable
2011-07-21 09:45:46.701 MyProject[7133:207] updateSeparately:Wifi is reachable
...
```

this shows that the NetworkStatus change has been noticed.... but why does it stay "NotReachable" for ~2 seconds?

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

PS. The same thing happens in the Apple's Reachability Sample Project (available here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Thanks for reading,

Mizer

Comment: have you tried running on device?

Answer (score 3):

probably irrelevant at this point (9 months later) but I was checking out this Reachability stuff and found a probable explanation for the 2 second delay from not reachable to reachable. Might be due to name resolving, as explained in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_7

> IMPORTANT: Reachability must use DNS to resolve the host name before
>   it can determine the Reachability of that host, and this may take time
>   on certain network connections.  Because of this, the API will return
>   NotReachable until name resolution has completed.  This delay may be
>   visible in the interface on some networks.

I guess changing the check from named host (apple.com by default) to an ip should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use this reachability class [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

I use it in all my apps and it works really well.